# writing a file path to a text file, how to omit the back slash?

Tags: java, file, io, backslash

I'm trying to write a file path or URL to a text file.

```
String myString = "http://example.com:96";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
fos.write(myString.getBytes());
```

I wonder why the back slash is written to the file even though we don't need an escape char for a forward slash??

```
http:\/\/example.com:96
```

(note that if I read back the URL string to a java program and print to the console, I don't see the back slash anymore. http://example.com:96  )

Is there a way to omit the back slash character?

Comment: If you defined `myString` as `http:\/\/example.com:96`, you don't need to escape forward-slashes - `String myString = "http://example.com:96";` will work just fine

Comment: Are you going to be reading the file back into your Java program or is it going to be used elsewhere?

Comment: @Xinzz What does it matter?

Comment: Just wondering if he's trying to read/write to a properties file.

Comment: I just edited the question. myString = "http://example.com:96" and I just want to write the ULR/filepath the way we normally see them so it  won't be OS/language specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to write exactly (in byte terms) what's in your string. So the backslashes will already be there. The stream won't be escaping them for you.

Note also, I would investigate [Writers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) for writing strings, and watch your character encoding! The above is using your default character encoding to determine the bytes to write to your file, and running this in a different environment may yield different results!